# Load jQuery into an iframe and get notified when it has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that I dynamically load HTML+JavaScript into. How can I load jQuery into that iframe and get some sort of call back to say it is ready? I can load it in with this code, but there's no way of telling when it has complete, there must be a better way?

```
var content = myFrame[0].contentWindow || jqPreviewFrame[0].contentDocument;
var doc = content.document || content;
var head = doc.head;
var jQueryScript = doc.createElement("script");
jQueryScript.type = "text/javascript";
jQueryScript.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js";
head.appendChild(jQueryScript);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595055/javascript-onload-event-how-to-tell-if-script-is-already-loaded).

Another way which I used in my project is to get jQuery javascript code through `XMLHttpRequest`. Pass the URL and wait for its `onreadystatechange` event. After code arrives successfully use `eval()` method to execute it. See if it applies to your case too.